# Except doesn't work with Laravel Collections

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-collection

I have the following code:

```
  $object = Object::with("prototypes.fields")->findOrFail($id)->get();

  $object_copied = $object->except(['id', 'prefix', 'prototypes']);

  dd($object_copied->all());
```

Last line returns collection with fields that should be except: `'id', 'prefix', 'prototypes'`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing:

```
$object = Object::with("prototypes.fields")->findOrFail($id)->get();
```

This is probably wrong.

You should either use:

```
$object = Object::with("prototypes.fields")->findOrFail($id);
```

or

```
$object = Object::with("prototypes.fields")->get();
```

The second thing is what you really want to achieve. `except` method might not be what you really want to use here if you want to get only some columns. In this case better option would be using `select` when getting data from database or maybe using `map` method.

Assuming in `$object` you have collection of object using `except` you will remove only some object from method (those with given keys) and keys in those collection will be numeric 0, 1, ... x so you should pass only numerical keys here if you want to not include first model in collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$object_copied = collect($object )->except('id', 'prefix', 'prototypes');`

Comment: The same result